# How do I do something GOTO could do, in Python - reload then restart outer loop

Tags: python, structure, goto

Here is a dumbed down version of my program that I am using as an example.

I know that using GOTO is bad practice, because it leads to sloppy and confusing code, however it would be perfect for solving this problem that I have (problem detailed at bottom of post).

```
def prompt():
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input:
        if input == '?':
            print help_o
        elif not user_input.isalpha():
            print "You entered bad characters"
        elif user_input == 'r': ##Restart
            ???????????
        else:
            return user_input


load_word_list() ##Load words into list

for word in wordList: ##Loop that needs to restart
    for i in range(5):
        to_speak = "Spell, %s" %word
        subprocess.Popen(['espeak', to_speak])
        answer = prompt()
        if answer != word:
            print "You got it wrong"


#Print results
```

At the Prompt, I want to reload the wordList list and restart the outer for loop.

With GOTO I could just put in place of ????... GOTO load_word_list().

But since this is Python (and Python is about good code), What is the Pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: The usual solution (in any language) is to reorganize your code so you don't need goto. Most simply, if you put the whole thing in a loop, you can continue to restart it and break to exit normally. (Of course Python doesn't have multi-level break and continue; the usual way around that is to refactor things into functions, so each one only has one level of looping.)

Comment: You could always use the 3rd party [goto](http://entrian.com/goto/) module :) (Disclaimer: you should _never_ use the etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another take on jsbuenos solution. This actually **does** re-run the outer for loop.

```
def prompt():
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input()
        if input == '?':
            print help_o
        elif not user_input.isalpha():
            print "You entered bad characters"
        elif user_input == 'r': #Restart
            raise RestartException
        else:
            return user_input


class RestartException(Exception):
    pass


while True:
    load_word_list() ##Load words into list
    try:
        for word in wordList: ##Loop that needs to restart
            for i in range(5):
                to_speak = "Spell, %s" %word
                subprocess.Popen(['espeak', to_speak])
                answer = prompt()
                if answer != word:
                    print "You got it wrong"
    except RestartException:
        # catch the exception and return to while loop
        pass
    else:
        # exit while loop
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

You could return a tuple from `prompt()`:

```
    elif user_input == 'r': #Restart
        return True, None
    else:
        return False, user_input
```

and

```
    restart, answer = prompt()
    if restart:
        break
    if answer != word:
        print "You got it wrong"
```

Comment: Don't you mean `return True, None`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class RestartException(Exception):
    pass

def prompt():
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input:
        if input == '?':
            print help_o
        elif not user_input.isalpha():
            print "You entered bad characters"
        elif user_input == 'r': #Restart
            raise RestartException
        else:
            return user_input


load_word_list() ##Load words into list

for word in wordList: ##Loop that needs to restart
    try:
        for i in range(5):
            to_speak = "Spell, %s" %word
            subprocess.Popen(['espeak', to_speak])
            answer = prompt()
            if answer != word:
                print "You got it wrong"
     except RestartException:
        pass
```

Comment: I think the OPs intention was to restart the outer loop and not the inner loop.

Comment: Indeed - but people got the right idea from here. That is enough.

Comment: I know. I was the one who gave you the upvote. I just thought you might like to amend your answer.

Comment: I know. I'd have if there was not an accepted answer with the correct form when I saw your comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undertand very much what you want to do, but you can remove the special case in `prompt` and handle the `'r'` special case in the for loop directly

Answer (score 0):

```
def prompt():
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input("enter words")
        if input == '?':
            print help_o
        elif not user_input.isalpha():
            print "You entered bad characters"
        elif user_input == 'r': #Restart
            return False
        else:
            return user_input


answer = True

while answer == True:
    load_word_list() ##Load words into list

    for word in wordList: ##Loop that needs to restart
        for i in range(5):
            to_speak = "Spell, %s" %word
            subprocess.Popen(['espeak', to_speak])
            answer = prompt()
            if answer == False:
                answer = True # reset for the while loop
                break # break to while loop
            elif answer != word:
                print "You got it wrong"

print results
```

Comment: jsbuenos solution does NOT (although it could, with little tinkering) reinitialize the wordList, which in my understanding was the whole question.